# How can I get first value only in each JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

x variable has a JSON value like below

```
let x = [{'a': 7, 'b': 8}, {'a': 1, 'b': 5 }]
```

the output should be

```
y = [7,1];
```

How can I get the JSON multiple object first value only? Thanks.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object properties are only reliably ordered in semi-modern browsers - your desired output may not be reliably determinable from code on running older browsers (unless you have a set order of the property names in an array, or unless the properties are numeric, or something like that). But, on newer browsers, you can `.map` the input array and extract the first value found by `Object.values` from the object you're iterating over:

```js
const x = [{'a': 7, 'b': 8}, {'a': 1, 'b': 5 }];
const result = x.map((obj) => Object.values(obj)[0]);
console.log(result);
```

Also note that, as always, [there's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). If you have an object or array, then you have an object or array, full stop. JSON format is a *method of representing an object in a string*, like `const myJSON = '{"foo":"bar"}'`. If there are no strings, serialization, or deserialization involved, then JSON is not involved either.

Comment: If Object.values not available, may be: const result = x.map((obj) => obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]);

Comment: Opps ..missed that

Comment: What about this `const result = x.map((obj) => obj.a);` can I use like this?

Comment: @imjayabal Sure, if you know the name of the property you want to extract, better to use that property - no need for `Object.values` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure about the key you want to access, then you just need to iterate from x and then push the result on your y.

```
let x = [{'a': 7, 'b': 8}, {'a': 1, 'b': 5 }];
let y = [];

for(let i in x) {
   y.push(x[i].a);
}

console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine `Array#map` with `Object.values()` to achieve this; the mapping would transform each item of your input array `x` to the resulting array `y`. For each item in the resulting array `y`, you would select the first value of the corresponding item from `x`.

To select the first value of an item in `x`, that item is passed to `Object.values()`. The result of `Object.values()` is an array of the values of that item, and it's by this that you can access and "map" the first value of each item in `y`:

```js
let x = [{'a': 7, 'b': 8}, {'a': 1, 'b': 5 }]

let y = x.map(item =>  Object.values(item)[0]);

console.log(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [];
x.forEach((elem) => {
    data.push(elem.a);
});
```